# Is it possible to avoid a breast reduction surgery via exercise?

Tags: exercise, spine, posture, breast

I've bumped into a few articles about women who had to take a breast reduction surgery because their large breasts were the reason of unacceptably high health issues, ranging from psychological issues to severe pains, abnormalities in body posture, or hampered mobility.

Now this issue doesn't apply to me, as I'm not a woman with large breasts (actually I'm not a woman in the first place), but still... Having such surgery done must a very tough decision for such women, as it means literally cutting away integral parts of one's body... I suppose if this problem did apply to me, I think that (to a degree) I'd rather suffer than accept such a surgery. This doesn't mean I don't understand people who take such a decision.

However, this makes me wonder about one thing. Psychological issues and inconvenience aside, it would seem that many health issues stemming from large breasts occur because their weight evokes on the spine greater pressure than it can withstand, hence the pains and body posture abnormalities. This leads me to the question whether strengthening back muscles or spinal muscles through exercise could mitigate these issues to the point of making the surgery unnecessary?

Comment: I had a brief look at the study posted below. There is no answer to your question, but at least an interesting point: women who had breast reduction surgery 'did not participate in physical activities because of the size of the their breasts. One study found that breast reduction patients avoided exercise because of feeling self-conscious of their breast sizes, and they were less likely to engage in self-care behaviors [...] Collins et al. found that breast reduction patients had difficulty participating in sports the majority of the time because of the size of their breasts. ' (continue)

Comment: That indicates that - even if it might be possible - affected women could tend not to *want* to exercise in order to make the surgery unnecessary. According to that, the psychological component might be stronger than the physical one and therefore adapting to live with large breasts might not even be an option for at least some patients.

Comment: This study referred by @AlexDeLarge is: http://utdr.utoledo.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1318&context=graduate-projects It was posted as an answer, but this answer was subsequently deleted.